# M2Eclipse deployes WEB-INF into WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I import Appfuse 2.1 into Eclipse 3.5 with m2eclipse. When I deploy it to tomcat, my web.xml goes to "WEB-INF\classes\WEB-INF\web.xml"
This issue is exactly the same with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764160/maven-webapp-with-eclipse-and-wtp-plugin-deploy-files-in-stranges-ways-in-tomcat).

I can't find any problems in org.eclipse.wst.common.component file:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="src/main/webapp"/>
<wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="src/main/java"/>
<wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="src/main/resources"/>
```

If I change `<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="src/main/webapp"/>` to 
`<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="target/appfuse_light_210m1-2.1.0-M1"/>`, it works.
But I don't want to modify org.eclipse.wst.common.component each time I import a project.
What's the cause of this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried doing a right-click->Maven->Update Project Configuration